# Gesture detection not working on layout

Tags: android

So I have tried this one tutorial which tells how the gestures work and I made a simple activity which detects the gesture and generates a toast. Now I am working on my project and made my homepage which has a simple Relative layout and an image view. The gestures work find there as well. Now I made a new Help page and tried everything I could but the gesture is not working for me. Is it because of the layout? as this one contains multiple relative and linear layouts. 
Given below is my Help activity. I wanna open speech recognition on LongPress (I am trying a toast here but its not working) 
Any help would be appreciated. I may be missing out something stupid

```
   package com.example.dell.optasia;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;
import static android.view.GestureDetector.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;

public class Help extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnGestureListener, OnDoubleTapListener {
    private GestureDetectorCompat GestureDetect;
    public MediaPlayer mp1;
    TextView textView;
    TextView answer5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(Help.this, R.raw.help);
        mp1.start();
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar(); //Actionbar
        ab.setLogo(R.mipmap.iconlaunch);
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); // set your desired color

        ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true); //shows logo
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); //shows home page
        TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        GestureDetect = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
        GestureDetect.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

        TextView txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question1);
        final TextView answer1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);

                txtview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (answer1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                            answer1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        else
                        answer1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                });

        TextView txtview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question2);
        final TextView answer2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
                txtview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        if (answer2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                            answer2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        else
                            answer2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                });
        TextView txtview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question3);
        final TextView answer3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
                txtview2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (answer3.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                            answer3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        else
                        answer3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
        TextView txtview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question4);
        final TextView answer4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);

        txtview3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (answer4.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                            answer4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        else
                        answer4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });

        TextView txtview4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question5);
        final TextView answer5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer5);
                txtview4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (answer5.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                            answer5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        else
                        answer5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });



    }

    //for the overflow actionbar

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    //for the actionbar menu items
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Play_ID:
                mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(Help.this, R.raw.manual);
                mp1.start();
                break;
            case R.id.Help_ID:
                startActivity(new Intent(Help.this, Help.class));
                break;
            case R.id.About_ID: {
                startActivity(new Intent(Help.this, LocationMain.class));
                return true;
            }
            case R.id.Contact_Us:{
                startActivity(new Intent(Help.this, ContactUs.class));
                return true;
            }
            case android.R.id.home:{
                startActivity(new Intent(Help.this, HomeScreen.class));
                return true;
            }
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return false;
    }
    //calls event for the gestures
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        GestureDetect.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if(mp1!=null)
        {
            mp1.stop();
        } return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        Toast.makeText(Help.this, "longpress!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a GestureDetector but you are never "hooking it up" to your View. Try changing your onCreate like this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
View v = new RelativeLayout(this);
v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
setContentView(v);
mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
        return mDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    }
});
```

or you can try this

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event)
  }
```

Comment: Nah it is not working for me. Throws nullPointerException. Btw I didnt do this "Hooking" stuff on my homepage but all the gestures work fine on it. Is it because of multiple relative views?

Comment: i have edditted answer pls check

Comment: I have this onTouchEvent already in my code. But it is not in the Oncreat method

Comment: check whther onDown() method fires some toast message

Comment: No it isn't. :/